# Pandas: filtering rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id           Date            Status
A         26-01-2022         begin
A         26-01-2022         failed
A         27-01-2022         begin
A         27-01-2022         in-process
A         27-01-2022         success
B         01-02-2022         in-process
B         01-02-2022         success
B         02-02-2022         begin
B         02-02-2022         failed
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Id           Date            Status
A         27-01-2022         begin
A         27-01-2022         in-process
A         27-01-2022         success
B         01-02-2022         in-process
B         01-02-2022         success
```

Need to keep all the activity of the Id where the status for that Id ends with **success** for that particular date.

tried grouping Id and Date, but stuck with dropping the relevant rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform('last')`:

```
df[df.groupby(['Id', 'Date']).Status.transform('last') == 'success']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `filter` by last value of `Status` column

```py
out = (df.groupby(['Id', 'Date'])
       .filter(lambda g: g['Status'].iloc[-1] == 'success'))
```

```
print(out)

  Id        Date      Status
2  A  27-01-2022       begin
3  A  27-01-2022  in-process
4  A  27-01-2022     success
5  B  01-02-2022  in-process
6  B  01-02-2022     success
```